# parallel execution of multiple modules in verilog

Tags: verilog

IN VERILOG, 
I would like to execute multiple multiplier "modules" in parallel. How do I do that?
and I also want to run these modules when ever at least one of my inputs change. I cannot use an always block for that... So how do i do it?

Comment: You don't "execute" modules in Verilog. In the same way as you don't "execute" ICs on a PCB. A Verilog `module` is a lump of hardware. You connect it to other lumps of hardware, just like you do ICs on a PCB. What have you tried so far? Have you designed this multiplier module?

Comment: Please explain what lead you to "I cannot use an always block for that", or show the code that you have for the multiplier, there are some misconceptions here about how verilog works. If you give a bit more info we might be able to inform and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the multiplier block is in and of itself a module (in your case), you can instantiate N of them to simultaneously execute them i.e. in parallel.

For example, assuming the module name is myMult(in1, in2, out)

```
myMult myMult1 (.in1(???), .in2(???), .out(???));
myMult myMult2 (.in1(???), .in2(???), .out(???));
myMult myMult3 (.in1(???), .in2(???), .out(???));
myMult myMult4 (.in1(???), .in2(???), .out(???));
```

And so on...

How long after providing the new input values will the output will be available, is entirely dependent on the internals of the myMult module.